# Can't start a video call when adding more than one users to opponents

Tags: quickblox

We can't start a video call when we adding more than one users to opponents. It works well when only one user(in your demo code) in opponents.

The following is the crash information:

```
07-02 15:53:19.022     499-1208/? E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: gralloc_device_alloc: attach special flag :Format32315659.
07-02 15:53:19.026      499-499/? E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: gralloc_device_alloc: attach special flag :Format32315659.
07-02 15:53:19.028     499-1441/? E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: gralloc_device_alloc: attach special flag :Format32315659.
07-02 15:53:19.281    7442-7673/com.quickblox.sample.videochatwebrtcnew E/VideoCapturerAndroid﹕ startCapture failed
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
            at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
            at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:423)
            at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:384)
            at org.webrtc.VideoCapturerAndroid.startCaptureOnCameraThread(VideoCapturerAndroid.java:345)
            at org.webrtc.VideoCapturerAndroid.access$200(VideoCapturerAndroid.java:72)
            at org.webrtc.VideoCapturerAndroid$2.run(VideoCapturerAndroid.java:332)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at org.webrtc.VideoCapturerAndroid$CameraThread.run(VideoCapturerAndroid.java:295)
07-02 15:53:19.290      135-135/? E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil﹕ checkDcf: not dcf type, dcf version value [80]
07-02 15:53:19.291      135-135/? E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil﹕ checkDcf: not dcf type, dcf version value [80]
07-02 15:53:19.291      135-135/? E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil﹕ checkDcf: not dcf type, dcf version value [80]
07-02 15:53:19.292      134-444/? E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil﹕ parseDcf: not dcf type, dcf version value [80]
07-02 15:53:19.292      134-444/? E/DrmMtkPlugIn﹕ onOpenDecryptSession() : failed to parse dcf file.
07-02 15:53:19.299      135-135/? E/FlvExtractor﹕ [ERROR]:Not an FLV file!!!
07-02 15:53:19.299      135-135/? E/FlvExtractor﹕ [ERROR]:[FLV]mtk_flv_extractor_recognize OUT
07-02 15:53:19.299      135-135/? E/﹕ SniffFLV return 0
07-02 15:53:19.339      499-512/? E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: gralloc_device_alloc: attach special flag :Format32315659.
07-02 15:53:19.362     499-1441/? E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: gralloc_device_alloc: attach special flag :Format32315659.
07-02 15:53:19.831    6945-6955/? E/com.miui.video.MiuiVideoWatermarkProvider﹕ ================getWatermarkList()======================
07-02 15:53:26.883    7442-7673/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2724
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.webrtc.VideoCapturerAndroid.doStopCaptureOnCamerathread(VideoCapturerAndroid.java:444)
            at org.webrtc.VideoCapturerAndroid.stopCaptureOnCameraThread(VideoCapturerAndroid.java:437)
            at org.webrtc.VideoCapturerAndroid.access$300(VideoCapturerAndroid.java:72)
            at org.webrtc.VideoCapturerAndroid$3.run(VideoCapturerAndroid.java:427)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at org.webrtc.VideoCapturerAndroid$CameraThread.run(VideoCapturerAndroid.java:295)
07-02 15:53:26.960      517-569/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '42543090 com.quickblox.sample.videochatwebrtcnew/com.quickblox.sample.videochatwebrtcnew.activities.ListUsersActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-02 15:53:26.963     135-7666/? E/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -2147483646
07-02 15:53:26.963     135-7666/? E/MtkCam/DisplayClient﹕ (7666)[enquePrvOps] mpStreamOps->enqueue_buffer failed: status[Unknown error 2147483646(2147483646)], rpImgBuf(0x42fc1478,0x44bb2000) (enquePrvOps){#356:mediatek/hardware/camera/client/DisplayClient/DisplayClient.Stream.cpp}
07-02 15:53:26.995     135-7666/? E/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -2147483646
07-02 15:53:26.995     135-7666/? E/MtkCam/DisplayClient﹕ (7666)[enquePrvOps] mpStreamOps->enqueue_buffer failed: status[Unknown error 2147483646(2147483646)], rpImgBuf(0x42fc1e08,0x44e74000) (enquePrvOps){#356:mediatek/hardware/camera/client/DisplayClient/DisplayClient.Stream.cpp}
07-02 15:53:27.003      517-569/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '42639cd8 com.quickblox.sample.videochatwebrtcnew/com.quickblox.sample.videochatwebrtcnew.activities.CallActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-02 15:53:27.029     135-7666/? E/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
07-02 15:53:27.029     135-7666/? E/MtkCam/DisplayClient﹕ (7666)[enquePrvOps] mpStreamOps->enqueue_buffer failed: status[Broken pipe(32)], rpImgBuf(0x42fc1988,0x46576000) (enquePrvOps){#356:mediatek/hardware/camera/client/DisplayClient/DisplayClient.Stream.cpp}
07-02 15:53:27.290    7750-7750/? E/AEE/DUMPSTATE﹕ copy_file: Copy /proc/7442/status to PROCESS_STATE failed(2), No such file or directory
```

How can I use the Android to achieve a multi users video call？

Answer (score 0):

A new version of Android WebRTC is to be released on August 27-28 and fix this. Multi-user video-calls are not available yet, QuickBlox is still working on implementing them.